# Оцените реализацию хеширования пароля

Tags: python, хеширование, password, password-hash

```
import uuid
import hashlib
 
def hash_password(password):
    # uuid используется для генерации случайного числа
    salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
    return hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest() + ':' + salt
    
def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
    password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
    return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()
 
new_pass = input('Введите пароль: ')
hashed_password = hash_password(new_pass)
print('Строка для хранения в базе данных: ' + hashed_password)
old_pass = input('Введите пароль еще раз для проверки: ')

if check_password(hashed_password, old_pass):
    print('Вы ввели правильный пароль')
else:
    print('Извините, но пароли не совпадают')
```

Comment: Плохо. Соль должна быть после пароля. Использовать uuid это стрельба из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: Ну и вообще, в криптографии лучше использовать готовую стандартную реализацию (я уверен для питона они есть), а не пилить свой кривой велосипед

Comment: Можете пожалуйста вкратце объяснить почему uuid, не подходит для генерации соли?

Comment: Хэш-функция sha256 считается слишком быстрой, на майнинг-ферме можно будет вскрыть хэши коротких паролей за вполне разумные сроки. Для сравнения, в «стандартных» реализациях PBKDF2 хэш-функцию sha256 вызывают примерно [390 000](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7119f40c9881666b6f9b5cf7df09ee1d21cc8344/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L298) раз, а у вас здесь всего один.

Comment: А ещё sha256 потребляет слишком мало памяти, что также упрощает брутфорс. Более современные алгоритмы хэширования паролей, такие как scrypt или Argon2, специально нагружают и процессор, и память для затруднения брутфорса